# Re-interpretation of the third law of thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, perturbation-theory, equilibrium, black-hole-thermodynamics

Consider the first paragraph of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0611004):

> A fundamental problem in thermodynamic and statistical
>   physics is to study the response of a system in thermal
>   equilibrium to an outside perturbation. In particular,
>   one is typically interested in calculating the relaxation
>   timescale at which the perturbed system returns to a stationary,
>   equilibrium configuration. Can this relaxation time
>   be made arbitrarily small? That the answer may be negative
>   is suggested by the third-law of thermodynamics,
>   according to which the relaxation time of a perturbed
>   system is expected to go to infinity in the limit of absolute
>   zero of temperature. Finite temperature systems are expected
>   to have faster dynamics and shorter relaxation
>   times—how small can these be made? In this paper we
>   use general results from quantum information theory in
>   order to derive a fundamental bound on the maximal rate at
>   which a perturbed system approaches thermal equilibrium.

Take a system in thermal equilibrium and perturb the system. How long does before the system relaxes back to a stationary, equilibrium configuration?

The excerpt mentions that this relaxation time cannot be made arbitrarily small, because *the third-law of thermodynamics stipulates that the relaxation time of a perturbed system is infinite at zero temperature*.

The [third-law of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_law_of_thermodynamics) is stated in the form

> The entropy of a perfect crystal at absolute zero is exactly equal to zero.

How can this statement be re-interpreted to mean that *the relaxation time of a perturbed system is infinite at zero temperature*?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/213094/third-law-of-thermodynamics-and-degenerate-ground-states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entropy goes to zero then the system becomes kinetically trapped in a single microstate (zero entropy) and therefore cannot relax.